# gen_server:call vs. just calling a function directly

Tags: erlang

Let's say there are two processes running in gen_server (started by the supervisor).  One calls a function in the other like this: `brother:function(Param)`.  It could also do `gen_server:call(brother, Param)`.  What are the use cases for each?  In both cases the first process waits for the function in `brother` to finish, so I don't understand when each should be used.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any difference directly. However, using `gen_server:call` (or `cast`) directly means that you are tying your *other* modules to the internals of the `gen_server`. Imagine that later on, you want to change the registration of `brother` so that it uses something else (for example, an external library such as gproc). Now you have to go and find every single place where you used `gen_server:call(brother, ...)` and fix it, *and* duplicate a lot of code to fetch the server name and so on. Overall it's just a lot easier to have that `brother:function(...)`

The same applies to changing the internal structure of calls or casts. It becomes a lot easier to just pass in everything as arguments to a function, and then use that function to construct the parameters. Like, say you use that function to create a record that's internal to the module.

So overall, it's mostly about encapsulation and separation of concerns. The module should generally take care of finding the proper server to send the call to, and the proper format for the calls.

Comment: Why have gen_server:call at all, if it's in the same module?  Can't we just do whatever you do in the call in the function, since either way we're waiting for completion?

Comment: Sometimes you can’t because your gen_server holds on to a state (the third parameter of `handle_call`) that your other processes don’t know.

Comment: Sometimes yes, but typically your `gen_server` will be encapsulating some sort of state that you don't want to reveal to other processes. It's essentially the same difference as in OOP between a `static` function and a regular method.

Answer (score 2):

> the first process waits for the function in brother to finish

No, it doesn't. Or rather, it depends on how `function` is defined. It'll often be something like

```
function(Param) -> gen_server:call(?MODULE, {function, Param}) 
%% or gen_server:call(?MODULE, Param) if there's only one kind of request
```

and the actual implementation will be in `brother:handle_call`.

Obviously in that case there's no difference between the results of calling `brother:function(Param)` or doing `gen_server:call` manually, but calling `brother:function` is a better practice: it allows to hide the details calling module has no business knowing and allows `brother` to change.